# Is it possible to add players to Xfce panel (volume) indicator applet?

Tags: xfce, indicator-sound, xfce-panel

A list of players is displayed when left clicking the volume indicator applet of Xfce panel.

[image]

But others are installed that I want to see there. Can I add them?

Comment: see this question (it's the same procedure for Xfce): http://askubuntu.com/questions/181508/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-the-sound-indicator-and-make-it-clickable-more-t - note that only players following the MPRIS standard to be controlled via dbus can be operated through the panel, and exactly these players should be added automatically on first run.

Comment: @Takkat - thanks for explaining the odd behaviour of deadbeef, smplayer, etc. i noticed a sort of workaround: making a non-supported player 'preferred' (instead of just 'interested') makes the player startable from the big 'play' button (but then the button cannot be used for play/pause; better then nothing).

Comment: Can you still **restart** a player after closing it using the Indicator?

Comment: @Takkat - i am not sure i understand correctly what you mean by "restart", so i specify that: i cannot close or restart a player **by using the indicator**, i can only start it; and yes, after starting it in this way (and then closing it), the player can be **started again** with the indicator (i tested that for deadbeef and smplayer, but under the limited condition that they are set as 'preferred' and have the play/pause and next/previous buttons: which do not work as intended but can be used to start the player...)

Comment: Good to know - will test this later, as some time ago applications which do not fully comply to MPRIS do not announce they are terminated to the dbus, hence can not restarted again with the panel Inidcator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You need to run [**Dconf Editor**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/).
(This is not limited to Xfce.)

[image]

[image]

But:

**As specified by [Takkat](https://askubuntu.com/users/3940/takkat) in a comment, this will fully work only for players controlled by MPRIS and DBus. This type of players will automatically be listed if installed.** (This means that dfconf will not be useful to add such programs, as they are automatically added, but only to set the preferred ones, with the play/pause and next/previous buttons, and to remove unwanted players by adding them as 'blacklisted'.)

A sort of **workaround** for "unsupported" players like DeaDBeef or SMPlayer is to set them as 'preferred', which will display the play/pause and next/previous buttons. The buttons will not work as intended for these programs, but **the players can be started with the 'play' button**.

In the image below, for ex., the unsupported DeaDBeeF (as well as the supported Audacious) can be started, but SMPlayer cannot. After adding smplayer in the list of 'preferred', a big 'play' button appears (after logout) which can be used to start the player - yet not for play/pause the media.

[image]

(Log out and in to activate the new settings.)

http://www.howtogeek.com/113897/how-to-remove-media-players-from-ubuntus-sound-menu-add-your-own/

---

Comment: This will only work for players controlled by MPRIS and DBus. These players should be automatically added. Other players will **not** work! The guide you linked to only helps to blacklist players.

Comment: @Takkat - all those i needed seem to be in the list of those that do work. so, i'll set as definitive. please edit to add more info if you feel like. (what would be those that don't work?)

Comment: @cipricus: the question then is, why did they not show up automatically as supposed to.

Comment: @Takkat - adding DeaDBeef works but not fully: it starts the program (the 'interested-media-players' aspect), but play/pause ('preferred-media-players') doesn't seem to work. on the other hand, **it starts only if it is 'preferred'**. i'll edit to add all that. but the main part of what i asked seem to work for me: adding new players and starting them from the list. although it's buggy, i have to set as my answer for i don't expect a better one.