# How to add a scrollable time bar to the sound indicator

Tags: sound, indicator, music

The Ubuntu sound indicator is nice because you can pause the playing song, go next or previous. Is there a way to add a scrollable time bar to that interface for the playing song?

I got the idea from a [mockup](http://soggybizkitlulz.deviantart.com/art/Ubuntu-Sound-Menu-Mockup-2-213295799) in [DeviantArt](http://deviantart.com)

[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

I think it's possible. I found this screen shot [here](http://kyleabaker.com/2010/08/19/rhythmbox-indicator-menu-finally-dropped/) even though it's from 2010 :-)

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

I would like a global solution not just for rhythmbox like shown in the screenshot above. A global solution means that it can be used  for controlling the current playing song irrespective of the media player used, be it VLC, Banshee, Rhythmbox, Audacious etc.

---

**EDIT 3**

Since a global solution is kinda impractical (see comments below), how about for VLC only? It's practically the only media player I use.

Comment: this link might be of help http://askubuntu.com/questions/181508/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-the-sound-indicator-and-make-it-clickable-more-t

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you are targeting? `indicator-sound` has got much code changes.

Comment: @Sneetsher I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. If you get a working version for 13.10 too, it would be nice.

Comment: @AvatarParto VLC and some others media players doesn't appear ever in the sound indicator menu, so I'm almost sure that there doesn't exists a global solution for controlling the current playing song irrespective of the media player used.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu How about for VLC only. It's the only player I use like 90% of the time?

Comment: Your screenshot is not from Unity, looks like Gnome2 or MATE, so I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: VLC has its own indicator and for now you probably need to edit the its source code to accomplish what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the source code for [indicator-sound](https://code.launchpad.net/indicator-sound).

However, I came up with a hack based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181508/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-the-sound-indicator-and-make-it-clickable-more-t).

(**For VLC**)

First of all, to add VLC to the sound indicator, you have to enable the MPRIS Dbus interface. (Follow [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-add-vlc-to-ubuntu-sound-menu.html) for more detailed explanation.) Once you have enabled it, VLC (along with other Music Players) can be controlled via D-bus interface.

For example, for VLC you can run the following command from terminal to seek 10s forward.

```
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek 10000000
```

You can read all the available functions from the MPRIS interface [here](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html).

Now based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181508/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-the-sound-indicator-and-make-it-clickable-more-t), you can create your own custom script to seek 10s forward, backward etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but seeing you have 3k reputation, allow me to give the 50 to @Vivek atleast  to raise his abit. Atleast you guys tried to find a solution though it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

For Gnome-Shell users (not Unity)

You can use gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer
```

Please go through below link, you can customize many things:

https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Looks Nice but sorry I'm using unity.

Comment: oops!...but I guess it can give idea how to implement same thing in unity.

Comment: The reputation is because you at least tried to find a solution for me. I won't mark it as answered though.

Comment: Thanks I found the question interesting...now I am trying to implement it in unity :).. I found this link interesting:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom Application indicator with 3 menu items viz. Rewind, Forward & Quit. I have tested it in unity it works fine. It can give you some idea. I am trying to make it look like picture provided by you. Meanwhile I am posting the code that I am using you can work on that too.

Requirement: mdbus2

Install it using: `sudo apt-get install mdbus2`

Below is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
To rewind and forward the currently playing song
depend on mbus2 and can be installed using sudo apt-get install mbus2
version 0.1 (public domain)

Author: Vivek Mishra
'''

import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
proxy = bus.get_object('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox','/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
player = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')

APPNAME = "Player Navigation"
ICON = "/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/totem.png"

from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as AI
from gi.repository import Gtk

# Forwards a song for 100 sec
def forward(item):
    player.Seek(100000000)

# Rewinds a song for 100 sec    
def rewind(item):
    player.Seek(-100000000)

def scroll(aai, ind, steps):
    print "hello" # doesn't print anything

def makemenu():
    ' Set up the menu '
    menu = Gtk.Menu()

    forward_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Forward')
    forward_item.connect('activate', forward)
    forward_item.show()

    rewind_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Rewind')
    rewind_item.connect('activate', rewind)
    rewind_item.show()

    exit_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    exit_item.connect('activate', Gtk.main_quit)
    exit_item.show()

    menu.append(forward_item)
    menu.append(rewind_item)
    menu.append(exit_item)
    menu.show()
    return menu

def startapp():
    ai = AI.Indicator.new(APPNAME, ICON, AI.IndicatorCategory.HARDWARE)
    ai.set_status(AI.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    ai.set_menu(makemenu())
    ai.connect("scroll-event", scroll)
    Gtk.main()

startapp()
```

Hope this helps. :)