# How can I integrate mpv media player into the Ubuntu sound menu?

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

I tried the following command to integrate [mpv](https://mpv.io/) into the Ubuntu sound menu.

```
$ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players "['lollypop', 'mpv']"
```

This adds an entry for mpv but it misses the playback controls.

[image: Screenshot mpv sound menu]

Comment: With clementine the playback buttons appear, when you start the program. Maybe that feature needs to be implemented in mpv Media Player. You might want to open an issue and label it as feature request on https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues I did not found any issue regarding sound indicator.

Comment: Thank you, @mondjunge! :-) Issue created: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/3767

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can integrate any music player (or other application) into the sound indicator [as shown here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181508/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-the-sound-indicator-and-make-it-clickable-more-t) but this will only make it controllable if the player supports dbus (mpris) controls.

Sadly this is [not the case for MPV](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/661).

There is an [external plugin](https://github.com/dodo/lua-mpris) which claims to add mpris support. I haven't tried it myself but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: thanks for your answer! On a side note, which player would you recommend that comes closest to MPV but supports dbus (mpris) controls?

Comment: Sadly the user script is not working on Ubuntu 16.10: https://github.com/dodo/lua-mpris/issues/7

Comment: Too bad - I can't help with a similar player. MPV is rather good and it is lightweight. Do you need video?

Comment: Yes, I prefer to have one player for both audio and video. Indeed, I like MPV a lot as well.